# Oracle SQL: how to concatenate text until reaches maximum size

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a case:

some script to reproduce:

```
 create table test_Txt(
 id   number(1),
 text varchar(2000)
 );
 
 insert into test_txt values(1,'BRUG HIDDEN 4. The student is obliged to justify the absence from educational classes within the specified period:
1) parents or legal guardians excuse the student''s absence by the end of the second week of the following month / for the previous month / in justified cases (e.g. a visit to a doctor), the parent or legal guardian may exempt some classes in person or in writing;
2) in the event of a student''s resignation from participation in non-compulsory classes, written information from the parent or legal guardian is required;
3) expected absence of a student for more than one week (e.g. stay in a sanatorium, hospital, chronic disease), parents or legal guardians are obliged to notify the class teacher within 3 days;
4) if the absence is not excused within the prescribed period, the class teacher explains the reasons for the absence with the parents or legal guardians;
5) information about frequent absenteeism of students is passed to the school pedagogue, parents are called
6)xfasdfkjasdgkdsethkgjaskgjbsajgbkjsdguihifafa');
 
 insert into test_txt values(2,'BRUG HIDDEN 4. The student is obliged to justify the absence from educational classes within the specified period:
1) parents or legal guardians excuse the student''s absence by the end of the second week of the following month / for the previous month / in justified cases (e.g. a visit to a doctor), the parent or legal guardian may exempt some classes in person or in writing;
2) in the event of a student''s resignation from participation in non-compulsory classes, written information from the parent or legal guardian is required;
3) expected absence of a student for more than one week (e.g. stay in a sanatorium, hospital, chronic disease), parents or legal guardians are obliged to notify the class teacher within 3 days;
4) if the absence is not excused within the prescribed period, the class teacher explains the reasons for the absence with the parents or legal guardians;
5) information about frequent absenteeism of students is passed to the school pedagogue, parents are called
6)xfasdfkjasdgkdsethkgjaskgjbsajgbkjsdguihifafa');
 
 insert into test_txt values(3,'BRUG HIDDEN 4. The student is obliged to justify the absence from educational classes within the specified period:
1) parents or legal guardians excuse the student''s absence by the end of the second week of the following month / for the previous month / in justified cases (e.g. a visit to a doctor), the parent or legal guardian may exempt some classes in person or in writing;
2) in the event of a student''s resignation from participation in non-compulsory classes, written information from the parent or legal guardian is required;
3) expected absence of a student for more than one week (e.g. stay in a sanatorium, hospital, chronic disease), parents or legal guardians are obliged to notify the class teacher within 3 days;
4) if the absence is not excused within the prescribed period, the class teacher explains the reasons for the absence with the parents or legal guardians;
5) information about frequent absenteeism of students is passed to the school pedagogue, parents are called
6)xfasdfkjasdgkdsethkgjaskgjbsajgbkjsdguihifafa');
  
 insert into test_txt values(4,'BRUG HIDDEN 4. The student is obliged to justify the absence from educational classes within the specified period:
1) parents or legal guardians excuse the student''s absence by the end of the second week of the following month / for the previous month / in justified cases (e.g. a visit to a doctor), the parent or legal guardian may exempt some classes in person or in writing;
2) in the event of a student''s resignation from participation in non-compulsory classes, written information from the parent or legal guardian is required;
3) expected absence of a student for more than one week (e.g. stay in a sanatorium, hospital, chronic disease), parents or legal guardians are obliged to notify the class teacher within 3 days;
4) if the absence is not excused within the prescribed period, the class teacher explains the reasons for the absence with the parents or legal guardians;
5) information about frequent absenteeism of students is passed to the school pedagogue, parents are called
6)xfasdfkjasdgkdsethkgjaskgjbsajgbkjsdguihifafa');

 insert into test_txt values(5,'BRUG HIDDEN 4. The student is obliged to justify the absence from educational classes within the specified period:
1) parents or legal guardians excuse the student''s absence by the end of the second week of the following month / for the previous month / in justified cases (e.g. a visit to a doctor), the parent or legal guardian may exempt some classes in person or in writing;
2) in the event of a student''s resignation from participation in non-compulsory classes, written information from the parent or legal guardian is required;
3) expected absence of a student for more than one week (e.g. stay in a sanatorium, hospital, chronic disease), parents or legal guardians are obliged to notify the class teacher within 3 days;
4) if the absence is not excused within the prescribed period, the class teacher explains the reasons for the absence with the parents or legal guardians;
5) information about frequent absenteeism of students is passed to the school pedagogue, parents are called
6)xfasdfkjasdgkdsethkgjaskgjbsajgbkjsdguihifafa');

 insert into test_txt values(6,'BRUG HIDDEN 4. The student is obliged to justify the absence from educational classes within the specified period:
1) parents or legal guardians excuse the student''s absence by the end of the second week of the following month / for the previous month / in justified cases (e.g. a visit to a doctor), the parent or legal guardian may exempt some classes in person or in writing;
2) in the event of a student''s resignation from participation in non-compulsory classes, written information from the parent or legal guardian is required;
3) expected absence of a student for more than one week (e.g. stay in a sanatorium, hospital, chronic disease), parents or legal guardians are obliged to notify the class teacher within 3 days;
4) if the absence is not excused within the prescribed period, the class teacher explains the reasons for the absence with the parents or legal guardians;
5) information about frequent absenteeism of students is passed to the school pedagogue, parents are called
6)xfasdfkjasdgkdsethkgjaskgjbsajgbkjsdguihifafa');
```

And Select:

```
SELECT t.*,FLOOR((sum_text)/3000)
        FROM   (SELECT id,
                       TO_CHAR(text) AS text,
                       LENGTH(text) AS len_Text,
                       SUM(LENGTH(text)) OVER(ORDER BY id DESC RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS sum_text
                FROM   test_txt) t;
```

What i want to achieve is concatenate texts until sum of them is less than 3000. If larger, then another text.

```
ID  LEN_TEXT    SUM_TEXT    FLOOR((SUM_TEXT)/3000)
6   1039    1039    0
5   1039    2078    0
4   1039    3117    1
3   1039    4156    1
2   1039    5195    1
1   1039    6234    2
```

And here goes problem: texts with group 1 when You sum them is greater than 3000. Text with id = 2 supposed to have group 2 but is 1.

Anyone has an idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT id,
       LENGTH( text ) AS text_len,
       match_num,
       SUM( LENGTH( text ) ) OVER ( PARTITION BY match_num ) AS total_len
FROM   test_txt
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY id
  MEASURES
    MATCH_NUMBER() - 1 AS match_num
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( a+ )
  DEFINE
    A AS SUM( LENGTH( text )) <= 3000
)
```

Which, for your sample data, outputs:

> | ID | TEXT_LEN | MATCH_NUM | TOTAL_LEN |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1039 | 0 | 2078 |
> | 2 | 1039 | 0 | 2078 |
> | 3 | 1039 | 1 | 2078 |
> | 4 | 1039 | 1 | 2078 |
> | 5 | 1039 | 2 | 2078 |
> | 6 | 1039 | 2 | 2078 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cc80fb9bc0f806d9c13406e85dcf7093)*

Comment: Nice!. Where do i get to learn this match_recoginze?

Comment: @q4za4 Just put "oracle match_recognize" into a search engine and you should get plenty of examples and the syntax is in the Oracle documentation for the [`SELECT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) statement under the "row pattern clause".